# AngularFire firestore not getting fresh written document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a cloud functions that writes a user document, for example an access token
Then after that function is called and awaited I do a get to read the document.

However, the document read is old.

The cloud function writes the document like this:

```
    await admin.firestore().collection('garminHealthAPITokens').doc(userID).set({

    oauthToken: urlParams.get('oauth_token'),
    oauthTokenSecret: urlParams.get('oauth_token_secret'),
    state: crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex')
  })

  // Send the response wit hte prepeared stuff to the client and let him handle the state etc
  res.send({
    redirect_url: REQUEST_TOKEN_CONFIRMATION_URI,
  })
```

Here is part of the code on the client side that:

```
const redirectURI = await this.userService.getCurrentUserGarminHealthAPIRedirectURI(); // Function updates token
              // This doesn't return the written token of the above but rather an older (prev) one
              const token = await this.userService.getGarminHealthAPITokenAsPromise(this.user);
```

Here is how I call the the AngularFire document get

```
public async getGarminHealthAPITokenAsPromise(user: User): Promise<{oauthToken: string, oauthTokenSecret: string, state: string}> {
    return this.afs
      .collection('garminHealthAPITokens')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .get({source: 'server'})
      .pipe(catchError(error => {
        return [];
      }))
      .pipe(take(1))
      .pipe(map((doc) => doc.data()))
      .toPromise();
  }
```

There is an explicit get from the server there but the results are not fresh

What am I missing?